# Error message using ImageJ MRI Retina Tool ijm

Tags: imagej, retina, mri

Can someone help me with this? Some images I can measure but some I cannot. Then this error message pops up. I measured all of them using same settings but some I can measure and some I can't.

Here is the my problem I'm having:

[image]

If anyone can help me please, I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the tool. If you can make available an image on which this is happening and the values of the options you use, I can try to find out what is going on.

Best regards,

Volker Bäcker

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) 
 you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) instead, 
 provide [answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)